# Clean way in Rails to conditionally change the link_to location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

SO i have this link_to

```
 <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
```

but if its an admin i want go to a different location like below...I know i can do this but is there a cleaner way

```
 <% if admin_user %>
 <li><%= link_to "Home", admin_path(current_user) %></li>
 <% else %>
 <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little cleaner

```
<li><%= link_to "Home", admin_user ? admin_path(current_user) : root_path %></li>
```

or where ever you computed admin_user, presumably in the controller, create an additional variable containing the appropriate path and use it in the view instead. e.g.

```
# in controller
home_path = admin_user ? admin_path(current_user) : root_path

# in view
<li><%= link_to "Home", home_path %></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible way, e.g. if you want to change the name of the link also:

```
<li><%= 
  link_to_if admin_user, "Home", admin_path(current_user) do
    link_to "Home", root_path
  end
%></li>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if